# find the number of nodes in a binary tree greater than x

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

```
public static int nodesGreaterThanX(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root,int k,int count)
{
    if(root==null)
        return 0;
    if(root.data>k){
        System.out.print(root.data + " ");
        count++;
    }
    int countLeft = nodesGreaterThanX(root.left, k,count);
    int countRight = nodesGreaterThanX(root.right, k,count);

    return count + countLeft + countRight;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BinaryTreeNode<Integer> root = takeInput();
    int count = nodesGreaterThanX(root, 2,0);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

i want to get the number of nodes greater than x(2 in this case) but my answer is not coming correctly and i am not able to find out the problem in my program
please dont change the logic if not needed and tell me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you're walking the tree from the root down, you don't need to propagate 'counts' downward at all--the fact that you are is resulting in repeated counting of nodes as they contribute to both `count`, `countLeft`, and `countRight`, since you increment `count` before passing it to `nodesGreaterThanX` for the children.

```
public static int nodesGreaterThanX(BinaryTreeNode<Integer> node, int k) {
  if (node == null) {
    return 0;
  }

  int countLeft = nodesGreaterThanX(node.left, k);
  int countRight = nodesGreaterThanX(node.right, k);

  return (node.data > k ? 1 : 0) + countLeft + countRight;
}
```

Comment: You need parens around the ternary so the countLeft + countRight gets added in either case. `return (node.data > k ? 1 : 0) + countLeft + countRight;`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis thanks--it's been some time and I guess I don't quite remember the precedence rules :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the `count` variable through the call tree, it's being counted over and over again as you recurse.

In each call you just need to:

```
return countLeft + countRight;
```

and add another `+ 1` if the current node meets the criterion.