# Finding the number of nodes with int data greater than x in a binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to recursively find the number of nodes that have int data greater than than a given int. This is being done on a binary search tree, so it makes things a bit easier in terms of finding the amount. However, my solution seems to be one-off on all of the tests I've run and I can't figure out why, see below:

```
private int numGreaterThan(Node r,int d) {
    if(r.data > d) return 0;
    return 1 + numGreaterThan(r.right, d);
}
```

I know I could just search the whole tree, but that would be inefficient and not really make use of the binary search tree's structure. Am I possibly overlooking something here? My thought process here was to just go right, as that is where the largest values are, but perhaps this is flawed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find the number of nodes in a binary tree greater than x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736391/find-the-number-of-nodes-in-a-binary-tree-greater-than-x)

Comment: @DeepanshuRathi I did see this question. Unfortunately, it doesn't. I am trying to make use of a binary search tree here, not just a binary tree. I do not want to visit nodes I do not have to, as that would not be making use of the structure of a binary search tree.

Comment: You still need to search right even if the current node doesn't match. If it does match you need to search left too.

Comment: Also your code counts nodes where node.data <= d, but your title says you want the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your code should check whether `r` is `null` before anything else.
- You can only return 0 when you have arrived at a `null`.
- Returning 0 when `r.data > d` is certainly wrong, as that node itself should be counted, and all the nodes in the right subtree
- Your code never looks in the left subtree. When `r.data > d` there can also be nodes in the left subtree that should be counted.

Here is a correction:

```
    private int numGreaterThan(Node r, int d) {
        if (r == null) return 0;
        int count = numGreaterThan(r.right, d);
        if (d < r.data) count += 1 + numGreaterThan(r.left, d);
        return count;
    }
```

Or using the ternary operator:

```
    private static int numGreaterThan(Node r, int d) {
        return r == null ? 0
             : numGreaterThan(r.right, d) +
                (d < r.data ? 1 + numGreaterThan(r.left, d) : 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to count nodes which has greater value than given int. But your base case returns from the function when the root value is lesser the given int, which is opposite behaviour.

The idea of using right-sub-tree is good, but instead of returning when greater value found you have to do the opposite.

```
private int numGreaterThan(Node r,int d) {
    if(r == null || r.data <= d) return 0;
    return 1 + numGreaterThan(r.right, d);
}
```

Edit: also you need to take care of the nodes when it `null`;

Comment: This is not correct. If `r.data <= d` there might still be nodes in `r.right` that are greater than `d`.

Comment: @trincot: since the tree is already in BST fashion, "there might be nodes in `r.right` that are greater than `d` "is actually invalid statement.

Comment: just check what happens when d=2, and you have root with data=1 and its right subtree has a subtree with 20 values between 3 and 100, in BST fashion, then your code will not count those 20 values.